# Shiny app radioButtons invisible in RStudio viewer pane

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

The RStudio (Version 1.2.1139 on macOS) viewer pane renders radioButtons (and FWIW, selected checkboxInputs) invisible. But these look and work fine in the browser, when 'Run External' is selected under the 'Run App' button. Below is a repro, and some screenshots.

**Addendum:** I note that `shinyWidgets::prettyRadioButtons()` resolves this issue immediately. Simply add `library(shinyWidgets)` at the top, and replace the call to `radioButtons()`.

```
# Reproduce radioButtons invisibility in RStudio viewer pane
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   radioButtons("Dunit"
               ,"Dose Units"
               ,c("µg"="micrograms",
                  "mg"="milligrams",
                  "g"="grams")
               ,selected = "milligrams"
               ,inline = TRUE)
   ,checkboxGroupInput("Dper"
                       ,NULL
                       ,c("/m²"="perBSA",
                          "/kg"="perKg",
                          "abs"="absolute")
                       ,selected = "perKg"
                       ,inline = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**In RStudio viewer pane:**

[image: How this Shiny app looks in RStudio viewer pane]

**In External browser:**

[image: How this Shiny app looks in Safari web browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Chromium (the component powering RStudio's viewer) on MacOS. You can work around it by adding `zoom: 1.0000001` or similar to the CSS that styles radio buttons for your Shiny app.

More info in this RStudio Github issue:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3751